# $_FILES[] is empty in jQuery generated form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, upload

I generated the next form in jQuery:

```
$('.content').append('
<form name="make_new_model_release" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input data-validate="validate" type="text" name="new_model_release_title" placeholder="Enter new model release title" />
<input type="file" name="newModelReleaseFile" id="newModelReleaseFile" />
<input type="submit" value="Create new model release" />
</form>');
```

Server side simple:

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

AJAX code:

```
var data = form.serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: formurl,
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function(data) {
        form.find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    complete: function(data) {
        form.find('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

after submitting the $_FILES array is empty.

1. I checked php.ini

> file_uploads=On |
>   upload_max_filesize=128M | post_max_size=128M

2. Temp folder is allowed for read and write
3. I tried to make `data: new FormData(formId)` - nothing changed, $_FILES array is empty.

Comment: I can't see your `formId`

Comment: i higly recommed to [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files) thoroughly. I've used that to upload files via ajax, that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used `jQuery('#dailyActivity').serialize()`,
It it is not working for `<input type'file'>`
Have look at this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shantaram/epd5svjq/) **Does not works**

and this one [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

> Data from file select elements is not serialized.

Have look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8758614/3425489

In you case try this

**To send `<input type'file'>` you may want to try this**

```
var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
```

or specify exact data for formdata

```
var formData = new FormData();
// Append your other Data
formData.append('newModelReleaseFile', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```

And you ajax call will be

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: formurl,
    data: formData,
    // THIS MUST BE DONE FOR FILE UPLOADING
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function(data) {
        form.find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    complete: function(data) {
        form.find('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```